# What is the best way to get rid of merge conflicts when pulling commits from master?

Tags: git, merge, rebase, conflict

After I branch from `master`, after a while, when I pull (other people's) code from `master` there are merge conflicts (i.e. package.json and package-lock.json).

I usually `git rebase master` my branch, but when I push my code, it shows other people's commits since I have branched off in the "Changed Files" section of the PR.

How do I keep my branch up to date with `master` without including other developers changes, just my changes for my branch?

Comment: I do not understand what it is you want to keep your branch up to date with that is not the other developers' changes. Can you give an example of an edit on `master` that you want to keep your branch updated with?

Answer (score 1):

This way has worked for me (assume a branch `develop` has branched off of `master`):

1. (on `master`): `git pull origin master`
2. (switch to `develop`): `git checkout develop`
3. (on `develop`): `git merge master`

Resolve merge conflicts 1 by 1 then `git commit` when prompted